# react-native : stack navigation into tab navigation whitout showing it

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So i have a bottom tab navigation into `app.js` with 3 tabs:
=> `map`
=> `user`
=> `settings`

```
<NavigationContainer>
<TabNav.Navigator initialRouteName='home'>
<TabNav.Screen name='home' component={Map} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="map-search-outline" color={color} size={30} style={style.iconStyle} />
            ),            tabBarLabel: (null)
          }} />
          <TabNav.Screen name='user' component={User} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="card-account-details-outline" color={color} size={30} style={style.iconStyle} />
            ),tabBarLabel: (null)
          }} />

          <TabNav.Screen name='settings' component={Settings} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="set-square" color={color} size={30} style={style.iconStyle} />
            ),            tabBarLabel: (null)
          }} />
        </TabNav.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

So I want to acces to a stack nav screen (`report` for exemple) anywhere into the children screens/components (a modal for exemple) of the `map` or the `settings` but not from the homescreen without showing it in the nav of the homescreen or the direct child of this homescreen, how can I do ?

In other words, I think I dont know where to write my hidden stack nav to be accessible from everywhere in the app. (but I understand how to pass it with the props)

Comment: I did not understand your intention. Could you try to be more specific or explain in a clearer way?

Comment: I just edited the post

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't understand your problem :(

Comment: made a new post with all the code - > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72757521/react-native-navigation-how-to-set-up-a-stack-navigation-in-a-child-modal