# react-native navigation, how to set up a stack navigation in a child modal?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

Struggling with the principles of the navigation.

here is my `app.js`

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import React from 'react';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import Settings from './src/containers/settings/index-settings';
import User from './src/containers/user/index-user';
import Map from './src/containers/map/index-map';

const TabNav = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={style.Main}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <TabNav.Navigator initialRouteName='home'>

          <TabNav.Screen name='home' component={Map} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="map-search-outline" color={color} size={30} style={style.iconStyle} />
            ),                tabBarLabel: (null)
          }} />
          <TabNav.Screen name='user' component={User} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="card-account-details-outline" color={color} size={30} style={style.iconStyle} />
            ),                 tabBarLabel: (null)
          }} />

          <TabNav.Screen name='settings' component={Settings} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="set-square" color={color} size={30} style={style.iconStyle} />
            ),                tabBarLabel: (null)
          }} />
        </TabNav.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Then we go to the container `index-map.js`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { enableLatestRenderer } from 'react-native-maps';
enableLatestRenderer();
import MapBar from '../../components/showMap';
const Map = ({ navigation }) => {
    // doing some stuff to calculate the coords
    const coords = {
                    latitude: 50.2151,
                    longitude: 4.95411
                } 
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={style.Main}>                
                <MapBar coords={coords} navigation={navigation} />                
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};
```

then into the component `showMap.js` :

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import { Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import SpreadTheMarkers from './showMarkers';
import { useFindAllBarAround } from '../hooks/queries-hook';

const MapBar = (props) => {
    const { isLoading, data, error } = useFindAllBarAround(props.coords);
    //this calculated all the markers data (long, lat, etc)

    return (
        <>            
            <MapView style={style.map}
                showsUserLocation={true}
                customMapStyle={mapstyle}
                loadingEnabled={true}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: props.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: props.coords.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.04,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.04
                }}>
                    <SpreadTheMarkers list={data} navigation={props.navigation} />
            </MapView>
        </>
    );
};
```

we go into the marker set up with the component `showMarkers.js`

```
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import SmallDescription from './smallBarDescriptions';

const SpreadTheMarkers = (props) => {
    const listBars = props.list.map(item => (
        <>
            <Marker
                key={item.id}
                coordinate={{
                    latitude: parseFloat(item.latitude),
                    longitude: parseFloat(item.longitude)
                }}
                image={
                    require('../img/icon_simple_100.png')    
                }
            >
                <SmallDescription barInfos={item} navigation={props.navigation} />
            </Marker>
        </>
    ));

    return (
        <>
            {listBars}
        </>
    )
}
```

then into the description of the markers into the component : `smallBarDescriptions.js`

```
import ModalInfos from './bar/modalInfos';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const SmallDescription = (props) => {
    const popupBarinfos = () => {        
         setModal(true);
    }
    const [modalVisible, setModal] = useState(false);
    const handleModal = (isModalActive) => {
        setModal(isModalActive);
    }
    return (
        <Callout
            onPress={() => popupBarinfos()}
        >
            <Modal
                animationType="slide"
                transparent={true}
                visible={modalVisible}
                onRequestClose={() => {
                    setModal(!modalVisible);
                }}
            >
                <ModalInfos infos={props} navigation={props.navigation} modalCallBack={handleModal} />
            </Modal>
 <Text >
                blabla // Showing some stuff 
            </Text>
        </Callout >
    )
}
```

Finally then into the component `modalInfos.js`

```
const ModalInfos = (props) => {
    const setModal = () => {
        props.modalCallBack(false);
    }
    return (
        <View>   
             <View >
                    <Text>some blablabla</Text>
             </View>
                 <Pressable
                     onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('edit')}
                 >
                     <Text >Edit</Text>
                 </Pressable>  
                 <Pressable
                     onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('report')}
                 >
                     <Text >report</Text>
                 </Pressable>                  
                    
                <Pressable
                    style={[styles.buttonClose]}
                    onPress={() => setModal(false)}
                >
                    <Text>✖️</Text>
                </Pressable>
            </View>
        </View >
    )
}
```

Can someone tell me what I exactly have to do to navigate into the screen `edit` and `report` with a stack navigation (or other) ?

And those screens will be re-used into the screen `settings` `<TabNav.Screen name='settings' component={Settings}/>` with differents props

Comment: You can define those screens outside the Tabbar stack too.

Answer (score 1):

```
const TabNav = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function BottomTabsNavigation() {
  return (

    <TabNav.Navigator initialRouteName='home'>

      <TabNav.Screen name='home' component={Map} options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="map-search-outline" color={color} size={30} style={style.iconStyle} />
        ),
        tabBarLabel: (null)
      }} />
      <TabNav.Screen name='user' component={User} options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="card-account-details-outline" color={color} size={30} style={style.iconStyle} />
        tabBarLabel: (null)
      }} />

      <TabNav.Screen name='settings' component={Settings} options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="set-square" color={color} size={30} style={style.iconStyle} />
        ),
        tabBarLabel: (null)
      }} />
    </TabNav.Navigator>
  )
}

const App = () => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={style.Main}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          <Stack.Screen name='BottomTabsNavigation' component={BottomTabsNavigation} />
          <Stack.Screen name='edit' component={Modification} />
          <Stack.Screen name='report' component={ReportBar} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

Then use navigation where it's needed with

```
const navigation = React.useContext(NavigationContext);
```

...

```
<TouchableOpacity
   onPress={() => navigation.push('edit', props.infos.barInfos) || setModal(false)}
>
```